# SpringFramework JUnit MergedAnnotations java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

Try ro run some unit tests in a Java SpringBoot application.

The unit test I run is :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppInitializer.class})
public class FilePropertyInjectionUnitTest {
   @Value("${geckoDir}")
   private String geckoDir;

   @Test
   public void whenFilePropertyProvided_thenProperlyInjected() {
      assertEquals(geckoDir,"C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
   }
}
```

And I got the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations

```
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizerFactory.isAnnotated(DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizerFactory.java:53)
at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.lambda$selectMethods$1(MethodIntrospector.java:97)
at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.lambda$selectMethods$0(MethodIntrospector.java:74)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:410)
at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:96)
```

I am using ItelliJ as IDE .

Comment: Could you please add pom.xml or build.gradle details?

Comment: Errors like this generally come from the fact you are mixing jars/modules from different versions of a framework, in this case Spring.

Comment: Yes I know. But not sure what I 'm mixing . Is a large project and have a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure this one out.I had to upgrade spring-test dependency to version 5.2.8:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I really went down the rabitt hole with this one

Answer (score 0):

Below is part of my POM. I don't know what jars are clashing.

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```